# C++ Overloading Output Operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a header file that looks like this:

```
#pragma once

//C++ Output Streams
#include <iostream>

namespace microtask
{
    namespace log
    {
        /**
         * Severity level.
         */
        enum severity
        {
            debug,
            info,
            warning,
            error,
            critical
        };

        /**
         * Output the severity level.
         */
        std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const severity& level);
    }
}
```

and a source file that looks like this:

```
//Definitions
#include "severity.hpp"

//Namespaces
using namespace std;
using namespace microtask::log;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const severity& level)
{
    switch(level)
    {
    case debug:
        out << "debug";
        break;
    case info:
        out << "info";
        break;
    case warning:
        out << "warning";
        break;
    case error:
        out << "error";
        break;
    case critical:
        out << "critical";
        break;
    default:
        out << "unknown";
        break;
    }

    return out;
}
```

that I am trying to compile into a dynamic library. Unfortunately, linking fails with this error message:

```
undefined reference to `microtask::log::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, microtask::log::severity const&)'
```

What am I doing wrong? I've checked other stackoverflow.com questions that seemed similar, but as far as I can tell, I have the format for overloading the operator correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your .cpp file, don't say `using`, but instead declare the proper namespace:

```
namespace microtask
{
    namespace log
    {
        ::std::ostream & operator<<(::std::ostream& out, const severity& level)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

In fact, don't say `using` casually at all if you can help it. In my opinion it should be reserved for explicit base member unhiding and ADL requests.

Comment: Well, that works. Now, so that I don't make the same mistake again, why was it not working before? (Ill accept your answer as soon as the timeout is up).

Comment: You were defining `::operator<<`, rather than `microtask::log::operator<<`. That is just a separate function, and the one you need was still missing. The permanent solution that even your grandkids will be grateful for is to never use `using` :-)

Comment: ah, I see, well that makes sense I guess. Idk, it just sort of threw me off because Im used to declaring implementations for class methods like that.

Comment: @root.ctrlc I believe the reason your version does not work is because your definition of operator<< in the .cpp is implementing ::operator<<(out, severity) but not microtask::log::operator<<(out,severity)

Comment: `using` is for, well, using.  It doesn't affect defining.

Comment: @root.citric: Hm... it really shouldn't work. ADL will sometimes make a name visible that isn't in the right namespace, so perhaps that managed to conceal something, but in general you have to define the same object that you declare, not a different one.

Comment: @KerrekSB I meant, how you can do class test{ public: void foo(); }; and then in the source file you would do void test::foo(){}. If I put the class test inside a namespace, as long as I use it with the using keyword in the source file, this has always worked for me.

Comment: @root.ctrlc: Hm, I'm not actually sure about the lookup rules; it's possible that if the *only* matching declaration is in a namespace, that namespace is searched. But since `operator<<` is already declared in other namespaces, this certainly won't work in your situation, and in general you should always put things in the namespace where they belong. Maybe someone else can enlighten us on the precise lookup rules.

Comment: @root.ctrlc: actually, I cannot reproduce what you claim. If you can make it work, please post it as a new question and ask why the lookup works.

Comment: While I can agree that using `using` too much is bad style, I can see useful situations. In situations where you are using the namespace qualifier in a particular scope a lot, it saves you time (and possibly refactoring cost) to pull that namespace into scope. However, placing `using` at file scope is nearly always wrong.  Make the `using` statement in the tightest scope possible.